# BGL: map objects to graphs

Tags: c++, boost

I need to be able to store a graph type Tree for every vertex in a given graph. I am trying to use `boost::ptr_map<vertex_desc, Tree> DESC` where `Tree` is a adjacency list graph type. After i create a Tree object `desc` and add the vertices I want, I try to store desc to the map like that `DESC.insert(std::make_pair(*vi.first, desc))` but the compiler doesn't allow it. If I 
do `DESC[*vi.first] = desc` the compiler doesn't complain but after that I encounter very strange behavior when i try to use the map. Should I use another way of storing the Tree object?

Comment: From what I found I understand that `DESC[*vi.first] = desc` is a very wrong way of storing an object to `std::map` (as `boost::ptr_map` is a wrapper of an `std::map` that uses pointers). You have to use either the `new` operator or something like `boost::ptr_map_insert` function that handles the insertion for you. But still i found using ptr_map to point to `boost::adjacency_list` graph a pretty difficult task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful about using `vertex_descriptor` objects outside of the graph to which they belong. Check out the table of iterator/descriptor stability/invalidation for the different container choices, from the [docs page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html). You need to use `boost::listS` for the `VertexList` parameter if you want vertex-descriptors to be always valid (unless being deleted).

That said, if you want anything to be associated to graph vertices, you should really put that into the vertex properties, especially with bundled properties. But if you can't modify it, then you should do as I said, i.e., make sure descriptors remain valid throughout graph operations.

Comment: I finally changed my implementation because the use of boost::pt_map messed up everything, the rules about what type or data structure you store in the map are very strict and I had to be very careful about the way I recover a tree and edit it, for example when I tried to recover a tree every other pointer to a tree in the same scope pointed to the tree I edited, so instead of that I now store each tree in the vertex using bundled properties(as you suggested).This a non-generic way for doing it,but at least I am able to work on the algorithm and test it's execution time. Thank you for the resp